# Recursion query that checks if X exists in a Prolog database

Tags: recursion, prolog

I'm trying to create a query `exists(X)` that returns true if X exists in a prolog database.

Prolog Database

```
store(best_smoothies, [alan,john,mary],
      [ smoothie(berry, [orange, blueberry, strawberry], 2),
        smoothie(tropical, [orange, banana, mango, guava], 3),
        smoothie(blue, [banana, blueberry], 3) ]).
store(all_smoothies, [keith,mary],
      [ smoothie(pinacolada, [orange, pineapple, coconut], 2),
        smoothie(green, [orange, banana, kiwi], 5),
        smoothie(purple, [orange, blueberry, strawberry], 2),
        smoothie(smooth, [orange, banana, mango],1) ]).
store(smoothies_galore, [heath,john,michelle],
      [ smoothie(combo1, [strawberry, orange, banana], 2),
        smoothie(combo2, [banana, orange], 5),
        smoothie(combo3, [orange, peach, banana], 2),
        smoothie(combo4, [guava, mango, papaya, orange],1),
        smoothie(combo5, [grapefruit, banana, pear],1) ]).
```

My attempt

```
exists(X) :- store(_,_,S), isIn(X,S).

isIn(X, [smoothie(X,_,_)|[]]).
isIn(X, [smoothie(N,_,_)|T]) :- isIn(X,T).
```

Surprisingly it only returns true for `blue`, `smooth` and `combo5`. Is there something wrong with my recursion? (I don't think so since it was able to read `blue`, `smooth` and all the way down to `combo5`)

Output that I'm getting

```
?- exists(combo1).
false

?- exists(X).
X = blue;
X = smooth;
X = combo5;
false
```

Appreciate any help on this. Many thanks!

**EDIT: Revised Attempt**

```
exists(X) :- store(_,_,S), isIn(X,S).

isIn(X, [smoothie(X,_,_)]).
isIn(X, [smoothie(N,_,_)|T]) :- isIn(X,T).
```

**EDIT: Fixed**

```
exists(X) :- store(_,_,S), isIn(X,S).

isIn(X, [smoothie(X,_,_)|_]).
isIn(X, [smoothie(N,_,_)|T]) :- isIn(X,T).
```

Comment: you can also replace `N` with `_` in `isIn`'s last clause, since `N` is not used in it anywhere else. it is a "singleton" variable - defined by not used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[smoothie(X,_,_) | []]` is the same as `[smoothie(X,_,_)]`.

`isIn( X, S )` is equivalent to

```
isIn( X, S ) :-
  last(  S, smoothie(X,_,_) ).
```

which explains you observations.

Comment: So essentially, I'm not going through the list :/

Comment: no, on the contrary, you're going through the list all the way to the end without ever stopping.

Comment: Would using a member predicate be much more effective?

Comment: I'm of the opinion that to learn the language it is best to first try implementing everything yourself. correctness first, efficiency later! so yes, your intended meaning for `isIn` is just like `member`, but first try fixing your code. it is a small change in its first clause, that's needed.

Comment: By first clause do you mean this sir? ```exists(X) :- store(_,_,S), isIn(X,S).```

Comment: the first clause of `isIn` is (was) `isIn(X, [smoothie(X,_,_) | []]).` it will succeed only for the very last element in the list (the 2nd argument with which `isIn` will be called). but you need it to succeed possibly for *any* element in the list, not only for the very last one. to achieve this, you only need to make a very small change in that clause. right now it says that the tail of the list is empty, `[]` (and that's what makes it work for the last element only), but you need it to say that the tail can be anything.

Comment: Ah I see, such a small change indeed! ```isIn(X, [smoothie(X,_,_)|_]).``` fixed it hehe

Many thanks!